# Modifying java code errors

Tags: java, swing, exception

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Menu2 {

    protected String[] entreeChoice = {"Rosemary Chicken", "Beef Wellington", "Maine Lobster"};
    private String menu = "";
    private int choice;
    protected char initial[] = new char[entreeChoice.length];


    public String displayMenu(){

       for(int x = 0; x < entreeChoice.length; ++x){
           menu = menu + "\n" + (x+1) + "for" + entreeChoice[x];
           initial[x] = entreeChoice[x].charAt(0);
       }
       throws menuException


       String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type your selection, then press Enter." + menu);
       choice = Integer.parseInt(input);
       return (entreeChoice[choice - 1]);
    }

}
```

I'm having an error on the `throws menuException`. It says: **illegal start of type**.
  I'm almost done with the code, it's just that the codes need to be modified (photo attached), and when I do it, I get errors on where to put the code.

[photo of code](http://tinypic.com/r/5duwl0/8)

Answer (score 2):

Depending of what you want to do (throw an exception, or declare that your method may throw an exception of that type) :

Either change it too :

```
public String displayMenu() throws menuException {

   for(int x = 0; x < entreeChoice.length; ++x){
       menu = menu + "\n" + (x+1) + "for" + entreeChoice[x];
       initial[x] = entreeChoice[x].charAt(0);
   }
   ...
}
```

Or :

```
public String displayMenu(){

   for(int x = 0; x < entreeChoice.length; ++x){
       menu = menu + "\n" + (x+1) + "for" + entreeChoice[x];
       initial[x] = entreeChoice[x].charAt(0);
   }
   if (someCondition)
       throw new menuException();
   ...
}
```

Comment: @Dan Come to think of it, the latter won't work, since the code that follows the `throw new ...` will become unreachable. Edited answer.

Comment: it's okay now. it should be MenuException, thats why im getting errors everytime. thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 2):

`throws menuException` should be ...

1. Decleared as part of the method signature and
2. Should throw an actual `Exception` class (not an already existing instance)...

For example...

```
public String displayMenu() throws MenuException {

   for(int x = 0; x < entreeChoice.length; ++x){
       menu = menu + "\n" + (x+1) + "for" + entreeChoice[x];
       initial[x] = entreeChoice[x].charAt(0);
   }
   //throws menuException


   String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type your selection, then press Enter." + menu);
   choice = Integer.parseInt(input);
   return (entreeChoice[choice - 1]);
}
```

You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others